# Replacing a character in a c string

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I'm having trouble replacing characters in my c string. I have a c string called bits initialized to a sixteen bit string of 0's and 1's.  What I'm trying to do is convert the strings into their twos complement versions.  What I've learned is a simple assignment such as

```
int twosComplement(int number,char *binary){
    printf("searching for twos complement\n");
    int temp=number * -1;
    if(temp<-32768)
        return 0;
    printf("%d\n",temp);
    char bits[17]="";
    int i;
    int x=0;
    int y;
for(i=15;i>=0;i--){
    y=pow(2,i);
    if(temp%y!=temp){
        temp=temp%y;
        strcat(bits,"1");;
    }
    else{
        strcat(bits,"0");
    }
    printf("%s\n",bits);
    x++;
}

for(x=0;x<16;x++){
    if(bits[x]=='0'){
        *bits="a";
    }
    else{
        strcat(bits,"1");
    }
    printf("%s\n",bits);
}
```

is illegial in C because bits is actually a pointer to the first character in the string so it complains about an assignment from integer to pointer without a cast.

The above is code for this function. The first part works correctly and creates the proper 16 bit representation of the positive number. In the next part, i want to look at each character of the string and replace with the alternate character. This code compiles but doesn't work because im concatenating.  Also, I don't think it's reading properly what digit each character is .

Comment: Seriously?  How about posting some more relevant code than one line.

Comment: A single code line, totally out of context, is meaningless.

Comment: You still don't show is the declaration for bits[].

Comment: yes my bad, i just replaced it. My question is how do i replace characters. It doesn't let me make a simple assignment of a character such as bits[7]='0'; So my comparison statements are getting errors above

Comment: Something like `bits[7] = '0';` is absolutely fine, so your error is obviously somewhere else. Can you post a short but complete compilable program that exhibits your error, along with a copy & paste of the actual error you're getting?

Comment: I just posted my actual function minus the last part of obtaining a twos complement representation. It compiles just not proper logic.

Comment: The code shown generates the one's complement value, not the two's complement. The code shown should be fine as long as the type of `x` is a plain integer type (rather than, say, a pointer to integer).  If it is not compiling, there is something wrong with the context you aren't showing us.  Please look at how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
or an MCVE [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your logic is fine, as mentioned, you obviously have something else going on. For instance, [this code](http://ideone.com/101qxi) works just fine.

Comment: Your new code is completely different.  The `*bits = "a";` assignment is bogus; you might mean `*bits = 'a';`, though it is not obvious why `a` is in use at all.  Note that this assignment always zeroes the first byte of the string; you should be using `bits[x] = '0';` and `bits[x] = '1';` as in the code that was previously on display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code compiles cleanly using GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks with the command line:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
        -Wold-style-definition -Werror bits.c -o bits
```

Source:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int twosComplement(int number);

int twosComplement(int number)
{
    printf("searching for twos complement of %d\n", number);
    int temp = number * -1;
    if (temp < -32768)
        return 0;
    printf("%d\n", temp);
    char bits[17] = "";
    int i;
    int x = 0;
    int y;
    for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        y = pow(2, i);
        if (temp % y != temp)
        {
            temp = temp % y;
            strcat(bits, "1");
        }
        else
        {
            strcat(bits, "0");
        }
        printf("%s\n", bits);
        x++;
    }

    printf("One's complement:\n");
    for (x = 0; x < 16; x++)
    {
        if (bits[x] == '0')
            bits[x] = '1';
        else
            bits[x] = '0';
        printf("%s\n", bits);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    twosComplement(23);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
searching for twos complement of 23
-23
0
00
000
0000
00000
000000
0000000
00000000
000000000
0000000000
00000000000
000000000001
0000000000010
00000000000101
000000000001011
0000000000010111
One's complement:
1000000000010111
1100000000010111
1110000000010111
1111000000010111
1111100000010111
1111110000010111
1111111000010111
1111111100010111
1111111110010111
1111111111010111
1111111111110111
1111111111100111
1111111111101111
1111111111101011
1111111111101001
1111111111101000
```

You still have to implement the `+1` part of two's complement.

Be wary of using `strcat()` in a loop like this. It leads to quadratic runtime behaviour as `strcat()` has to skip over the previous content before adding the new character, so it skips 0+1+2+3+4+...N-1 characters, which is N(N-1)/2 bytes skipped in total.

Comment: that's the last part so i figure i start at the last bit, if it's 1 change to 0 and move to the left until i reach a 1 in which case i change it to a 1 and break out of the loop.

Comment: Getting the earlier parts working reasonably is sensible before dealing with the `+1`.  I'm not sure that `temp` and negation is helping you; the generated string looks like the binary representation of +23 rather than -23.  Using `pow()` is also overkill.

Comment: what would be a better way of determining the binary string representation

Comment: This loop works: `for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((1 << i) & number)
            bits[15-i] = '1';
        else
            bits[15-i] = '0';
        printf("%s\n", bits);
    }` and is consistent with your second loop.  You could also rephrase the whole operation to translate the bit pattern of `temp` into the answer; that avoids you having to deal with `+1`.  I was mainly getting you past compilation hurdles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler implementation of what you're trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void binary_string(uint16_t number, char * output) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 16; ++i ) {
        if ( number & 0x8000 ) {
            output[i] = '1';
        } else {
            output[i] = '0';
        }
        number <<= 1;
    }
}

void complement(uint16_t number, char * output) {
    binary_string(number, output);

    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        if (output[x] == '1') {
            output[x] = '0';
        } else {
            output[x] = '1';
        }
    }
}

void complement_better(uint16_t number, char * output) {
    binary_string(~number, output);
}

int main(void) {
    char bits[17] = {0};
    uint16_t number = 57801;

    binary_string(number, bits);
    printf("Before conversion: %s\n", bits);

    complement(number, bits);
    printf("After conversion : %s\n", bits);

    return 0;
}
```

and outputs:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./tc
Before conversion: 1110000111001001
After conversion : 0001111000110110
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$
```