# Removing a character from a string in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, c-strings

So I'm doing a past paper question about functions/characters/pointers. I've come across a problem in my code and need help understanding it.

More specifically, I am having problems with question B) ii), which requires me removing a colon from a string.

My idea was to take the string, make a pointer and point directly to the colon, then replace this colon with the next character that proceeds it. Then replacing the other characters after the colon with the character ahead of it, until it reaches NULL.

When it comes to compiling, it compiles just fine, but gives me segmentation fault: 11 .What's going on? how can I fix this? Is there something I am not understanding? Thanks.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLdsW.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int locate_colon(char* x) //Question B) i)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(*x != '\0')
    {
        if(*x == ':')
        {
            return i;
        }
        i++;
        x++;
    }
    return -1;
}

char* remove_colon(char* x) //Question B) ii)
{
    int y,i,j;
    y = locate_colon(x);
    i =0;
    j =1;
    while(*x != '\0')
    {
        x[y+i] = x[y+j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return x;
}

int main() //Testing if functions work by running through compiler
{
    int x;
    char colon[] = "Colon: 123";
    char* colonptr;
    colonptr = colon;
    x = locate_colon(colonptr);
    printf("%d",x);

    //B) ii)
    char* y;
    y = remove_colon(colonptr);
    while(y != '\0')
    {
        printf("%s",y);
        y++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You sure you want to reset `i` and `j` to `0` and `1` respectively for each iteration in `remove_colon`?

Comment: if your `remove_colon()` function ever does return, it will necessarily be the case that the return value (`x`) points to an empty string, because that's the only way the loop can exit.

Comment: @Downvoter ok I fixed the code, but still come up with segmentation fault.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing a character in a c string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371246/replacing-a-character-in-a-c-string)

Comment: By wording, your approach sounds correct, if it is expliciting only 1 character is being replaced.

Comment: `remove_colon()   while(*x != '\0') { ...} ` does not move the null character.

Comment: Much simpler to just use memmove() after finding the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop in `remove_colon()` should be:

```
while(x[y+i] != '\0')
{
    x[y+i] = x[y+j];
    i++;
    j++;
}
x[y+i]= '\0';
```

and

```
while(y != '\0')
{
    printf("%s",y);
    y++;
}
```

should just be:

```
printf("%s",y);
```

or another option:

```
printf("%s",colonptr);
```

Comment: Then you'd have to null terminate after the loop is finished, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @SGM, yep (fixed).

Answer (score 0):

In his now-deleted answer, @Giorgi pointed out this fragment of your code, which is valid C, but is nevertheless quite wrong:

```
while(y != '\0')
{
    printf("%s",y);
    y++;
}
```

Variable `y` is a pointer to `char`, so `while (y != '\0')` is equivalent to `while (y != NULL)`, which some people would prefer to write as simply `while (y)`.  C does not define any way in which incrementing a non-null pointer will yield a null pointer, so if the behavior otherwise were well defined then this loop would never exit.

In fact, however, the body of the loop dereferences `y` (indirectly, via `printf()`) and increments it.  Before too many iterations, `y` will point outside the memory allocated to the object it originally pointed (in)to, and after that, the behavior of dereferencing it is undefined.  A segmentation fault is a common observed outcome of this particular kind of UB.

I suspect that you meant to write `while(*y != '\0')`, but that still seems odd, for you would end up printing a sequence of tails of the string, whereas it seems you want to print just one string.  In that case, it is unclear to me why you are using a loop here at all.  What's wrong with simply

```
printf("%s",y);
```

?

Of course, that's not the only thing wrong with your code, as has been pointed out in comments, but it likely explains the segmentation fault that is the subject of your actual question.

Comment: Interesting explanation, yes I was meant to write:  while(*y != '\0') and ye it is abit odd now that I think of it. Thanks alot!

Comment: @emuterisa `printf` prints out the string up through the null character. There is no need to loop. If you wanted to loop and print a single character then you can do `printf("%c",*y);` and keep the loop. Again this is pointless when compared to do it he `printf("%s",y);` without the loop.